# Creating a table in postgres using pandas and psycopg2 gives me an error

Tags: pandas, database, postgresql, data-science, psycopg2

I am trying to create a database in postgres database using pandas and psycopg2.
The syntax are fine but still gives me an error like:
**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[67], line 9
7 sql = "CREATE TABLE linux (Distribution, {})".format(', '.join(column_names))
8 # Execute the statement
----> 9 cur.execute(sql)
11 # Commit the changes
12 engine.commit()
SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ...tion_Commitment, Forked_From, Target_Audience, Cost, Status)**

These are the things i tried.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
engine = psycopg2.connect(dbname="pandas", user="postgres", password="root", host="localhost")

cur = engine.cursor()
# Define the table
column_names = [
                "Founder", 
                "Maintainer", 
                "Initial_Release_Year", 
                "Current_Stable_Version", 
                "Security_Updates", 
                "Release_Date", 
                "System_Distribution_Commitment", 
                "Forked_From", 
                "Target_Audience", 
                "Cost", 
                "Status"
               ]
sql = "CREATE TABLE linux (Distribution, {})".format(', '.join(column_names))
# Execute the statement
cur.execute(sql)

# Commit the changes
engine.commit()

# Close the cursor and connection
cur.close()
engine.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify data type for each column like shown below.
Change data types to those that are actual in your case.

```
schema = [
    ("Founder", "varchar(50)"),
    ("Maintainer", "varchar(50)"),
    ("Initial_Release_Year", "date"),
    ("Current_Stable_Version", "varchar(20)"),
    ("Security_Updates", "varchar(50)"),
    ("Release_Date", "date"),
    ("System_Distribution_Commitment", "varchar(50)"),
    ("Forked_From", "date"),
    ("Target_Audience", "varchar(50)"),
    ("Cost", "numeric(10, 2)"),
    ("Status", "varchar(10)")
]
sql = "CREATE TABLE linux (Distribution varchar(30), {})"\
    .format(', '.join(map(' '.join, schema)))
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked.
Actually, I was following a video on YouTube, and I too thought it strange that the data type wasn't mentioned.